# Get value/text from ListView or ListBox item

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, runspace

I have an issue with getting the value (text) from ListView selected item.

Besides, I am not using MVVM, it is powershell runspace.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Post_Depl_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Post_Depl_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Post_Depl_App" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="false" Background="#0060a9">
        <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
        
        <Style x:Key="FocusTextBox" TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=NumText, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=NumText}"/>
           </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    
 <ListView Name="SiteList" Height="530" Width="700" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,350,0,100" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI SemiLight" FontSize="20" 
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
        SelectedIndex="0">    
                <ListViewItem Content = "Australia"></ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Content = "Chile"></ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
```

And here is the powershell where I have troubles. Probably finding the right property:

```
$SiteCheck = $SyncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([System.Func[String]{$SyncHash.SiteList.SelectedItem.ToString()})

        if($SiteCheck -eq "Australia"){
            (Get-Content -path C:\Post_Setup\temp.txt -Raw) -replace 'SiteVar','AU' | Set-Content -Path C:\Post_Setup\temp.txt
        }
        elseif($SiteCheck -eq "Chile"){
            (Get-Content -path C:\Post_Setup\temp.txt -Raw) -replace 'SiteVar','CL' | Set-Content -Path C:\Post_Setup\temp.txt
        }
```

I suppose the issue lies in this line:

```
$SiteCheck = $SyncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([System.Func[String]{$SyncHash.SiteList.SelectedItem.ToString()})
```

It doesn't work for ListView or ListBox.
However this works perfectly for ComboBox:

```
$SiteCheck = $SyncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([System.Func[String]{$SyncHash.SiteBox.Text})
```

Does anybody know the best way to get selected item value as a text from ListView/Box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the type of `SelectedItem` is `ListViewItem`. You need to get a value of `ListViewItem.Content` property.

You can specify `SelectedValuePath` which is the path (property name) in `SelectedItem` used to get the `SelectedValue`.

```
<ListView Name="SiteList" Height="530" Width="700" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,350,0,100" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI SemiLight" FontSize="20" 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="Content">    
            <ListViewItem Content = "Australia"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content = "Chile"></ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Now the `SelectedValue` contains value of `ListViewItem.Content`, so read it in the PowerShell.

```
$SiteCheck = $SyncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([System.Func[String]{$SyncHash.SiteList.SelectedValue.ToString()})
```

Comment: Magic! Thank you very much!